# Navigational error

Tags: menus, navigation, links, homepage

Basically I have an image for a header and I changed the link behind that to go to the main website and was planning on making a news option in the menu to link to the blogs main page, after changing the link of the image I no longer had a link to the main blog page which because of that created an extra menu option called "Home" which goes to the main blog page but I cannot figure out where this is to change as its not in the menu with the rest of my navigational buttons.

In short, how to change the Home page to be called "News" and have a different place in the menu?

If you need to see the blog to see what I mean then it's on [blog.lendfair.co.uk](http://blog.lendfair.co.uk).

http://wordpress.org/themes/constructor/

Comment: Take a look [at Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)...

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Edit the Contructor theme

The [Constuctor theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/constructor) checks the theme options and then includes the home link based on the option value.

The code that adds the Home link is located in
[`/wp-content/themes/Constructor/libs/Constructor/Main.php`](https://code.google.com/p/wp-constructor/source/browse/trunk/libs/Constructor/Main.php).

```php
// show link to homepage
if ($this->_options['menu']['home']) {
    echo '<li id="home"><a href="'.home_url().'/" title="'.get_bloginfo('name').'">'.__('Home', 'constructor').'</a></li>';
}
```

**Link Text**

To change the name of the link you need to edit this line.

```
__('Home', 'constructor')
```

**Link Location**

To change the location of the link your options are rather limited. You can place it at the beginning or the end of the dynamically generated menu by modifying the code.

### Option 2: Use a custom menu

Instead of editing the code as mentioned above, you can specify a menu in the WP Dashboard under **Appearances->Menu**. When you specify your own menu you have complete control over what links appear and where they will be placed. Here's is more info on how to do that. http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Comment: I have tried these options but thats whats strange about my error, its not in the menu anywhere because thats where i thought it would of gone, i believe it has something to do with this code as this is what i changed to be able to link the header to a different site.

Comment: <?php if (is_home() || is_front_page()) { ?>
     <h1 id="name"><a href="http://www.lendfair.co.uk/" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); echo " &raquo; "; bloginfo('description');?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
    <?php } else { ?> 
   <div id="name"><a href=" <?php echo home_url(); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); echo " &raquo; "; bloginfo('description');?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></div>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand your problem. Sorry I couldn't help.